# Transforming string values in a dataframe using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to add a column of values based on an existing column, I thought
a dictionary approach would work. It didn't.

I have a column (`ERP_CODE`) with repeating numbers from 1-9 `[1,2,9, 7, 9, 4...]`
which I would like to transform to readable strings.

What is the most elegant way to do so? So far I tried:

```
Condition={1:'SingleOddball', 2:'SingleEasyTracking', 3:'SingleHardTracking', 4:'EasyTrackEqualEmphasis',
           5:'EasyTrackOddballEmphasis', 6:'EasyTrackTrackingEmphasis', 7:'HardTrackEqualEmphasis', 8:'HardTrackOddballEmphasis',
           9:'HardTrackTrackingEmphasis'}

for rown in range(0,len(df)):
    df.Condition[rown]=Condition[df['ERP_CODE'][rown]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`:

```
df['New'] = df['ERP_CODE'].map(Condition)
```